Define $\rho(A)=\mu(A \cap E)$ for $A \in \mathcal{A}$. Prove $\int f(x) d \rho=\int f(x) \chi_E(x) d \mu $
This is problem 2 of chapter 11 Product measure "Real Analysis for Graduate Students" by Bass.
Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a measure space, let $E \in \mathcal{A}$, and define $\rho(A)=\mu(A \cap E)$ for $A \in \mathcal{A}$. Prove that if $f$ is non-negative and measurable, then
$$
\int f(x) d \rho=\int f(x) \chi_E(x) d \mu .
$$
I'm guessing you can probably prove this by showing it's true for indicator functions and the conclude via linearity + density? But I'm trying to use Fubini's Theorem to do this problem since that is what is taught in this section. My attempt at a solution is as follows.
Write
$$f(x) = \int \chi_{t < f(x)}  - \chi_{t < 0} dt$$
\begin{align}
    \int f(x) \chi_E(x) d \mu &= \int \left(\int \chi_{t < f(x)}  - \chi_{t < 0} dt\right) \chi_E(x) d\mu \\
    &= \iint \chi_{t < f(x)} \chi_E(x) dtd\mu - \iint \chi_{t < 0}\chi_E(x) dtd\mu \\
    &= \iint \chi_{t < f(x)} \chi_E(x) d\mu dt - \iint \chi_{t < 0}\chi_E(x) d\mu dt
\end{align}
After swapping integrals I'm not sure how to proceed.

I don't think this works. The very definition of integral on a measure space involves approximatoon by simple functions, so that proof should be acceptable.

This is a standard technique for such problems:
Suppose $A$ is measurable, then $\int 1_A d\rho = \mu (A \cap E) = \int 1_{A \cap E} d\mu \int 1_A 1_E d\mu$.
If $s = \sum_k \alpha_k 1_{A_k}$ is simple and non negative, then
the equivalence follows by linearity and expanding the characteristic functions of intersections.
Finally, let $s_n$ be a sequence of simple functions such that $s_k(x) \uparrow f(x)$ for all $x$, then the monotone convergence theorem shows that
$\int f d \rho = \lim_n \int s_n d \rho = \lim_n \int s_n 1_E d \mu = \int f 1_E d \mu$.

You mean monotone convergence theorem at the end (DCT would work if $f$ was integrable).

@peek-a-boo Yes, thanks for catching that!
